# type object 'SignupForm' has no attribute 'validate'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-allauth

I'm extending de User predefined of the Django Auth. With this:

```
#models.py
class Estudiante(models.Model):
   user    = models.OneToOneField(User)
   carrera = models.IntegerField('carrera', choices=CARRERA_CHOICES)
   carnet  = models.CharField(max_length=8)
   horas   = models.IntegerField('horas')


class SignupForm(forms.Form):
  carrera = models.IntegerField('carrera', choices=CARRERA_CHOICES)
  carnet  = models.CharField(max_length=8)

class Meta:
   model = Estudiante
   fields = ('carrera', 'carnet')

def save(self, user):
    user.carrera = self.cleaned_data['carrera']
    user.carnet = self.cleaned_data['carnet']
    user.save()


#admin.py
admin.site.register(Estudiante, SignupForm)
```

And I'm receiving this error when I request the login page:

```
AttributeError at /
type object 'SignupForm' has no attribute 'validate'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    localhost
Django Version: 1.6.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
type object 'SignupForm' has no attribute 'validate'
```

I'm using AllAuth, Django 1.6

Comment: Not sure whether the `django` framework adds constructors by default. If not, adding constructor that initialize the member data and the base classes should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least four out-and-out errors here, plus you are also doing a few things that are strange or unnecessary.

So, the errors: Firstly, the second argument to `admin.site.register` is an `admin.ModelAdmin` subclass, not a Form. That's the immediate cause of your error. You need to define a subclass and set its `form` parameter to your form.

Secondly, your form is a subclass of `forms.Form`, not `forms.ModelForm`. You need to use a ModelForm in order to get the relationship between the form and the model.

Thirdly, you have an indentation error: the Meta and the save() method need to be indented inside the form class, at the same level as the fields - otherwise they simply won't be recognised.

And fourth, the save method is expecting a `user` value, which won't be passed. And what you're trying to do with that user is *extremely* odd: you're trying to set the carrera and carnet fields onto that User. But those are fields of Estudiante, not of users.User: you haven't actually subclassed or extended User anywhere, so that model is completely separate and only linked via the `user` OneToOneField.

What you probably should be doing is make Estudiente a subclass of AbstractUser, and then setting `AUTH_USER_MODEL` to that model, as described in [the authentication docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).

Comment: Thank you!! Mostly works, now I need to do a few adjustments because I use Allauth, but the error is gone. The indentation error was my bad copying the code to the page. Noob.